# Disable onclicklistener on rows when clicked Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm very new to java and Android studio, and I'm making one card game for practice as well as to do something practical while learning (as I'm learning by my own).
So to explain in short, there will be 2 rows of 4 cards at top and bottom (I used linear layout to fit those), and these cards will be clickable, which will move them to `ImageView` at central area when they are clicked. Up to this I have done everything fine.
But now I want to make things such that whenever card gets clicked in one row, that whole row will be disabled till card in another row is clicked, then again remaining cards in that row will be disabled and first row would be made clickable.
In short I want to make those rows as different players which would be clickable in turns. I had one idea (which might be very dumb as I'm new to whole thing) in which I have set `onclicklisteners` on both linearlayouts containing 4 cards each, and in Onclick method in them I have added `Onclicklisteners` on each of that card. I was thinking that by doing this, if I disable `Onclicklistener` on linearlayout after clicking, those on all cards in that layout will be disabled too, but I don't know how to disable the button.
If my approach is correct then pls tell me how do I disable listener on layouts on clicking. If not suggest other logic. Thanks
In below code usercards are imageviews,on clicking they disappear (invisible) from there place and move on to central place as described before

```
layout1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            usercard1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setCardImage(cards.get(0), card1ondeck);
                    usercard1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });

            usercard2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setCardImage(cards.get(1), card1ondeck);
                    usercard2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });

            usercard3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setCardImage(cards.get(2), card1ondeck);
                    usercard3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });

            usercard4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setCardImage(cards.get(3), card1ondeck);
                    usercard4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });

        }
    });

    layout2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            user2card1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setCardImage(cards.get(4), card2ondeck);
                    user2card1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });

            user2card2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setCardImage(cards.get(5), card2ondeck);
                    user2card2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });

            user2card3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setCardImage(cards.get(6), card2ondeck);
                    user2card3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });

            user2card4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setCardImage(cards.get(7), card2ondeck);
                    user2card4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: Whatever btn you want to disable just put ` layout2.setOnClickListener(null)`

Comment: Create 4 methods,  2 methos (e.g. disableTopRow,disableBottomRow) that will disable all image card and enable on view (pass view as parameter), and 2 for enable other that enable all views.

Comment: @piyush that's it? I mean will it disable all 4 images in it once *I click on layout*? And how to re enable them once another row gets clicked. I need to do that again and again turn by turn, maybe loop is necessary then?

Comment: @Himesh can u explain little more pls, and if possible give some raw code?